# wubi's error while installin ubuntu 12.10 on windows 7

Tags: wubi

i got an error while using wubi to install ubuntu 12.10 on windows7 and all the instructions were correct, the error said ( 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_into' ) please help and thanks

Comment: Could be a failed `md5sum` check (reference http://pad.lv/989991). You can confirm by checking the log file in the `%TEMP%` directory named `wubi-12.10-rev273.log`

Answer (score 0):

it is possible md5hash issue, so just delete that file, clean up your windows (if i remember it was something like cleanup disk, or try any program that find i fix errors inside of windows, remove unused and not needed applications from windows, and completely prepare sistem for it) in fact you need to download new ubuntu iso image and look for md5hash to match. then just burn on cd. i beleive that can solve problem, but anyway you need new download.